# How to query the second column of a JOIN table?

Tags: php, sql, join

I would like to query the name of the friends of person n°4, so the numbers in 'otherPerson_id', but my attempt only query the id or name in 'person_id'. How could I ask to query the informations about the friends of person n°4, and not the information about person n°4 itself?

Here is my attempt :

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT p.idperson, p.name FROM person p INNER JOIN people_friends pf ON p.idperson = pf.person_id AND p.idperson = 4";
        $res = $connexion->query($q);
        $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        while($record = $res->fetch()) {
            echo $record[name];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

the table : (so when I look for the friends of person n°4, I would like it to return 1 and 7 )

[image]

EDIT :

```
CREATE TABLE people_friends
(
  person_id integer NOT NULL,
  otherperson_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT people_friends_pkey PRIMARY KEY (person_id, otherperson_id),
  CONSTRAINT people_friends_person_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (idperson) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT people_friends_person_id_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (idperson) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)



CREATE TABLE person
(
  idperson integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50),
  map bytea,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idperson)
)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think we need the schema of person and people_friends table.

Comment: .......ON p.idperson = pf.person_id AND (p.idperson = 4 OR pf.person_id = 4). You can try replacing the consecute query.

Comment: Paul Lo is right. It depends on the table structure. Is `name` available in the `people_friends` table for instance?

Comment: @PaulLo I edited my post, NavaStha I would like only the friends of person n°4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

pFriend.idperson, pFriend.name

FROM people_friends pf 

INNER JOIN person pFriend on pf.otherperson_id = pFriend.idperson

WHERE

pf.person_id = 4
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work (it does not return anything as if there is an error, the page is blank white). I edited my post if this can help.

Comment: Try it in MySQL Query Browser and see what it returns there or what error you get there. My query should give you exactly what you want, this is a pretty simple query btw that you need.

Comment: @peterPetrov you were right, I forgot the semicolon :) It works fine, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a WHERE clause where you check the pf table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.idperson
               ,p.name 
FROM person p 
  INNER JOIN people_friends pf 
    ON p.idperson = pf.person_id 
WHERE pf.otherperson_id = 4
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. He is expecting to return `otherperson_id` of 1 and 7 for a `person_id` of 4.